# Identifying and reading Microsoft Office lock files

Tags: python, excel, ms-office, office-interop

I'm writing something that monitors a folder, and whether a file is an office document, and is locked for editing, is relevant. This is in Python.

I need any information I can get on these files. In a perfect world, a spec for their contents (seems to be '\tLocking User's Name\x00\x00\x00...') and their naming convention would be great, but super-duper open and helpful though Microsoft famously are, it doesn't seem to documented anywhere.

Any other code I could look at that's doing similar things would be great, if anybody's aware of any projects that might include that?

My thinking was that they were created as files with the above content, named like office file, but with '~$' and prefixed, and dropping the first two characters, as long as the pre-extension part of the name stays longer than 6 characters.

i.e. file.docx -> ~$file.docx, 123456789.docx -> ~$3456789.docx. Unfortunately, that's not always true: xlsx files drop no characters, regardless of length. Does anybody have any other information on this?